# Finding the average number of visitors per day using Piwik

Tags: analytics, visitors, usage-data

How can I use the Piwik API or other available Piwik tools or features to find the average number of visitors per day during a date range?

I can find the number of user for a day and the total number of users for a date range but I can't find the Average number of user per day for a date range. I can find the average number on my own my dividing (Total Visits/Number of days) but I need to have this stat available for non technical users.

Comment: Why don't you just do the (Total Visits/Number of days)?  If you are using the API, it would imply you have a programming language that can do division.   You could even do that calculation client side using JavaScript when you output these numbers to HTML.

Comment: I'm not using the API, I assumed this was possible with the API but i have no clue how to use it.